# Learning notes on guitar in higher positions (instant recognition)

Tags: classical-guitar, sight-reading, memorization

I have found after playing guitar for several years that I am not so good at instantly recognising most notes on the guitar higher than the 5th (or perhaps higher than the 7th) position. I often still have to think a little or work it out, which makes me slower at sight reading (and in my general knowledge of the fret board). 
I have found that on average, the lower positions on the guitar are used more in classical guitar repertoire, which may be why.

Does anyone know any classical guitar music books with music written only in the 5th position and then only in the 9th position...or which focuses on higher position sight reading...or something similar? 
I am able to play most music so do not mind difficulty of the pieces...although I think I would prefer pieces on the easier side (say between grade 4-grade 7) as I am looking just to use it to help with recognising and memorising the notes in the higher positions of the guitar. 
Thank you.

Comment: A lot of sight-reading will help

Answer (score 5):

Frederick Noad's [**Solo Guitar Playing - Volume 2**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Solo-Guitar-Playing-II-Classical/dp/0825613078/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1512600011&sr=8-3&keywords=noad%20solo%20guitar%20playing) has chapters with short pieces specifically designed to improve sight-reading in higher positions. These appear alongside a wonderful selection of well-known and lesser-known pieces, that aid the development of specific techniques, while also developing knowledge of different eras of repertoire. I regularly return to both Noad Solo Guitar Playing books (but volume 2 in particular), for my own practice and to study with my Grade 5-8 pupils.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Estudio del Ligado by Barrios, for 1st string learning.

Overall, Cavatina by Stanley Myers is nice for high position playing.